# Variance for an image histogram in java

Tags: java, image-processing

I am trying to calculate the standard deviation for an image in java. I am using rast.Sample to get each grey level and then I am taking it away from the mean and squaring it.

My code is:

```
public int standardDeviation(BufferedImage source)
    {
    int width = source.getWidth();
    int height = source.getHeight();
    int totalPixels = width * height;
    int temp = 0;
    int VarianceSum = 0;
    double SumSquared = 0;
    int mean = mean(source);
    double variance = 0;
    int StandardDeviation = 0;
    Raster rast = source.getRaster();

    //Loop through rast getting each grey level.
    for(int i =0; i<width; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
            {
                temp = rast.getSample(i,j,0);
                VarianceSum += (temp - mean);
                SumSquared = Math.pow(VarianceSum,2);
            }
        }

    variance = SumSquared/totalPixels;


    System.out.println(temp);
    System.out.println(VarianceSum);
    //System.out.println(SumSquared);
    System.out.println(totalPixels);



    return StandardDeviation;

    }
```

I am doing something silly! Please help

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Also, use getData() instead of getRaster if you are not going to modify it

Comment: the value for standard deviation is returning as 0.

Comment: You have multiple errors, for example on how you accumulate VarianceSum. It should be (temp - mean)^2, THEN accumulate. What you really should do is use your debugger and examine each variable, to see that temp, Variance and SumSquared have the values you expect for each iteration of the loop. If you are using Eclipse, it has a wonderful debugger.

Comment: VarianceSum += Math.pow((temp - mean)2);
??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate over the width two times. Will crash if width != height. Also see my comment